# Can an MSI that was kicked off programmatically be cancelled without user interaction?

Tags: windows-installer, cancellation

Let's say I kick off an MSI using a command like this: "msiexec.exe /qb /i mypackage.msi" and then the MSI starts to do it's thing. Can an MSI started in this fashion be "cancelled" automatically without the user manually clicking the 'Cancel' button?

[image]

The MSI window is showing as this and I'm wondering if there is any way that an MSI can reach this scenario automatically, without the user clicking that 'Cancel' button which is now grayed-out.

Note: someone claimed that they didn't hit the Cancel button I think they really did. I'm just wondering if anyone knows for sure whether or not the MSI calls cancel on itself if maybe an error or something happened.

Comment: Can you explain your use case?  Is this for cancellation testing or something?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, /qn wouldn't have any UI.  The screenshot shows a /qb!  (Basic UI and disable cancel button )

I'm 99% certain that MSI doesn't expose an API for requesting the cancellation of a running MSI.  Perhaps if you have a custom EXE that uses the API to initiate the installation transaction you could then call an API to cancel it.

Comment: I don't want to cancel it. I just need to know if it's possible that the MSI itself triggered the cancel or if it HAS to be done by the user by clicking the Cancel button. Basically, someone claims they didn't hit the Cancel button I think they actually did.

Comment: Did you log the install?  Look at event viewer?  I can think of a number of scenarios (UAC elevation prompt, installer failure, custom action returns userexit)  that would cause an installer to either not begin or to stop and rollback.   Doesn't mean anyone hit the cancel button though.

Comment: Would it show 'Canceling ...' if it was doing a rollback?

Comment: Not sure how I can trigger it to do a rollback. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't mention how you build your MSI.  This is what I use: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixfailwhendeferred.html

Comment: Install shield standard msi installer with no custom actions.

Comment: There must be custom action - that would be very unusual, even if you added none there are probably some that IS generates. Look in the CustomAction table of the raw MSI file. To get to the point, if a CA returns ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT then it will show as canceled by the user.